# Angular $routeProvider not working for Apache Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, route-provider

I'm having a pickle with this at the moment. I'm running this angular front-end locally (localhost) with a Apache Server on Linux. When I try to access localhost, everything works great and I get my index.html. But now I have a link in index.html which should redirect the user to localhost/users. But I cant seem to get this working, I have tried every single solution on SO, but nothings seems to be working. Maybe some of you see what I'm doing wrong?

my app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('linkrec', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider

        .when('/users', { 
            templateUrl: '/users.html', 
        });
});


app.controller('UsersController', [ '$http', function($http) {
    var linkrec = this;
    linkrec.users = [];

    $http.get('https://localhost:9443/users').success(function(data){
        linkrec.users = data;
    });
} ]);
```

})();

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="linkrec">
    <head>
      <title>LinkRec</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="linkrec.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

      <h1>LinkRec</h1>
      <div class="container" ng-view>
            <a href="/users"><h2>Users</h2></a>
            <h2>Vacancies</h2>
            <h2>Groups</h2>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

my .htaccess used to be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.html/#!/$1 
</IfModule>
```

my .htaccess now

```
# Apache .htaccess

# angularjs pushstate (history) support:
# See http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url/
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Does anybody spot my mistake? The angular files are there and are correctly linked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(I would have posted a comment because I'm not a 100% sure of my answer, but my rep is too low)

I see you have turned on html5mode, so I think your .htaccess file isn't correctly adjusted to this.

Try the following .htaccess code

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>`